# Why is P(A |B) + P( A |B') ≠ P(A)?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

The only explanation I could come up with is that when using Bayes Theorem, the denominators don't match up.

But is there a more intuitive explanation that can be verbalized?

Comment: If $A$ and $B$ are independent then automatically $A$ and $B^c$ are independent. In that case the equality in the title becomes $P(A)+P(A)=P(A)$ which is of course not true in general.

Comment: Why do you think they should be equal?? If you can verbalize why you think that, then maybe we can explain why you're wrong.

Comment: How could $P(A|B)+P(A|B')=P(A)$ be true if it happens that $P(A)=1$?

Comment: I initially thought along the lines of: the probability of A given B happens and given it doesn't happen should add up to just probability of A. This probably doesn't help much as I much phrasing it in English rather than mathematical notation

Comment: It's like asking, if 40% of North Dakotans and 50% of South Dakotans are Republicans, why doesn't that mean that 90% of all Dakotans are Republicans? If a switch hitter bats .300 lefhanded and .280 right handed, why isn't he batting .580?

Comment: Instantly clicked!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example take 2 coin flips, the two events are $A=$'The first coin flip is heads' and $B=$'The second coin flip is heads'.

Then $P(A|B)=P(A|B^{C})=P(A)=0.5$, but clearly $0.5+0.5\neq0.5$.

There is no reason that these two probabilities should add up to $P(A)$, conditional probability is very different from the probability of an intersection.